# Palindromic numbers, code not working

Tags: c

Can someone tell what wrong with my code?

This code is attempting to deduce a palindrome for numbers from 100-999

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int  temp, n, reverse = 0, rem;
    n = 100;
    while ( n <= 999)
    {
        temp = n;
        while(temp!=0)
        {
            rem = temp%10;
            reverse = reverse*10+rem;
            temp/=10;
        }
        if ( reverse == n )
        {
            printf(" %d \t", n);
        }
        n = n + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort when posting.

Comment: Am voting to close too, no effort, had to take liberty in reformatting the code. Shows laziness on OP's part. We are not here to do work for you. Show us what you have done/debugged/tried?

Comment: Is it giving an error message (if so, what)? What test data did you use and what did the function return. Please clarify what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be setting `reverse` back to 0 for each new `n`

```
while ( n <= 999)
{
    reverse = 0; # <== otherwise you are using old value in reverse
    temp = n;
    while(temp!=0)
```